# Compiling C++ program using H5Cpp.h header file

Tags: c++, macos, hdf5

I'm need to create a HDF5 file. I'm using the H5Cpp.h header file. 
I'm trying to compile the C++ code below on OSX 10.11 El Capitan.

```
#include "include/hdf5-1.10.0-patch1/c++/src/H5Cpp.h"
using namespace H5;

const int NX = 5;
const int NY = 5;
const H5std_string  FILE_NAME( "SDS.h5" );
const H5std_string  DATASET_NAME( "IntArray" );

int main(){
  int i, j;
  int data[NX][NY];          // buffer for data to write
  for (j = 0; j < NX; j++){
    for (i = 0; i < NY; i++)
      data[j][i] = i + j;
  }
  H5File file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
  hsize_t dimsf[2] = {NX, NY};
  DataSpace dataspace(2, dimsf);
  DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet(DATASET_NAME, PredType::NATIVE_INT,
                       dataspace);
  // Attempt to write data to HDF5 file
  dataset.write(data, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
  return 0;  
}
```

I keep getting this error,

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Here's the verbose output - https://gist.github.com/gkarthik/e21d2f83baffc2d2eb1b883696c44df8

Thanks!

Comment: What version of HDF5 are you using? I suppose that you have to compile the HDF5 library yourselft to use it with Mac. At the HDF5 webpage I only see the pre-built binaries for windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

- I think that you have to compile the HDF5 library yourself if you haven't the pre-built binaries. At the HDF5 website there are no pre-built binaries for Mac (as far as I can see).
- In windows, to compile a C++ application to use the HDF5 library you have to indicate to the linker the following dependencies (in this order), maybe in mac is also imperative:
  szip.lib zlib.lib hdf5.lib hdf5_cpp.lib
- If you download some pre-built binaries, there is a file that will indicate the steps to compile your C++ program. In windows it is called: "USING_HDF5_CMake.txt" and "USING_HDF5_VS.txt". You can find these files for example [here](ftp://ftp.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/).